# About C language File IO.How to calculate average by File input(fgets)

Tags: c

The task is to presume a file already exists that the file is One score per line,
and we don't know how many scores in the file. we need it to Calculate the average in each score.
one example:

```
 test.txt=21
          43
          32
          54
```

in test file. we need it to `(21+43+32+54)/4`;
and my progress is using for loop to input score value.
next is input the value by `fgets()`.

but my code average is not action.
I think my code fault is 's'in `fgets` means string. is it right?
and then my input is string but the calculation is on double.

and I don't know where to change my code.
if you have any helpful opinion then please let me.
[image]

Comment: You misuse `one`. It is array of `int` not `char`.

Comment: `sum=sum+one` makes no sense. What do you mean?

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on. It will tell you about some problems.

Comment: Next time, post the code, not an image.

Comment: ok too much thank you for comment !!

Comment: sum=sum+one     mean is sum is a variable that space to store the sum how can i change this code ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

see in your code you are using sum as an integer and one as an array and using the code

```
sum = sum + one;
```

which is wrong as a whole array can not be added as one value at a time as u have used.
so instead of unnecessary and wrong use of array u can use a float variable and scan the values of the file to it(using fscanf) and add it to the sum and update it every time new line gets scanned.

we are traversing the file here using feof() which is used to look for the end of file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
 float sum=0,count=0,avg,val; // declaring necessary variables
 FILE *fin;
 if ( (fin = fopen("c:￦￦Ubuntu20.04￦￦scores.txt","r"))== NULL )// file is opened
 printf ("file can't be opened");
 else
{
while(!feof(fin)) // using while loop till the end of file 
 {
fscanf(fin,"%d",&val);
sum += val; // Math for sum here
count++;
}
}
 fclose(fin);
avg = sum/count; // math for average calculation
printf("\n the average is : %.3f\n",avg"); // printing average till 3 decimal points
 return 0;  
 }
```

the above code will work for you for any length of file.
P.S. if u want to improve english https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duolingo&hl=en_IN&gl=US  use this app will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using `getline` function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int num = 0, sum = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    FILE* fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t read;

    fp = fopen("scores.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Fail to the file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

each line is a line of a number (string)
by using the `atoi` function cast it to integer:

```
    while(read = getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {
        sum += atoi(line);
        num++;
    }
    
    avg = (double)sum / num;
    printf("%d scores read\nscores avg: %lf\n", num, avg);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

the result of avg will be the average of all the numbers in the file,
for example from your file the out put will be:

```
4 scores read
scores avg: 37.500000
```